# Wired network on computer to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I just got myself a wifi capable cell phone, but I dont have a wireless internet at home. I do have a wired unlimited internet connection on my computer, and I wonder whether there is any gadget that I can plug into my computer (maybe at the usb port?) with which I can turn my computer into a wifi access point? I mean, a dongle or something which will enable me to connect my phone to my computer's internet through wi-fi? Also, I dont know anything about networking, so would it be hard for me to set up a secure wifi point? Thank you for reading this question through. Hope I can buy some sort of adapter which is comparitively cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a usb wireless adapter, the following vid shows the general process, I would choose to use security on the connection (ie dont follow the exact example in this video).https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6rZUgYWVcQ . However as the previous answer suggested the best option is to get a router that lets you connect in a more secure manner.

Comment: Thank you gays,buy a wireless router, is my last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible to do what you want from a dongle, firstly a cheap one will not cut it, and secondly it is very hard to configure, you be better to buy a wifi router and put it in between your computer and internet connection and it will save you a lot of work and will mot likely be cheaper

Comment: This seems like it should have been a comment since you say its possible but don't go into much detail.  Why exactly won't a cheap USB 802.11 dongle work for instance?

Comment: @Ramhound why.... because the work involved in transmitting the signal instead of receiving it require a lot more work from the dongle, which in turn cause it to overheat and burn you need a good manufactured one to not do this which aint cheap

Comment: @AndrewCrawford - It requires no additional work for a dongle to be a transmitter instead of a reciever.